# iOS app crashes on splash screen, no stack trace on Xcode Organizer crash reports

Tags: ios, xcode

It started happening in the latest release version. There is no description, stack trace regarding the crashes. Most of the users experience this kind of an error. They open the application, and it gets stuck in the splash screen (launch screen).

I couldn't reproduce it in any of the simulators/devices regardless of the iOS versions. And the users with different iOS versions (10.3, 10.2, 13.4  etc.) experience the same crash.

[image: Crash Report Screenshot]

Comment: What is “the splash screen?” Do you mean launch screen?

Comment: Yes, that is right, launch screen

Comment: So maybe there’s something wrong with your launch screen. Is it a launch screen storyboard?

Comment: It is, but we haven't changed it from the start, and this crash started happening in the latest release. And the changes aren't that much related with the starting of the application.

Comment: Well, as you rightly point out, there is no stack trace, so it's impossible to proceed. Either you're crashing before your code even starts to run or something is wrong with the crash reporting process. So you're on your own; we have no crash log and we have no info on what you are doing during launch. Simple rule of thumb about what to do on launch: _nothing_. Get the heck out of the way and allow the app to launch! You have very little time to launch before the WatchDog kills you dead, don't add to the burden. Do tasks _after_ launch is _over_.

Comment: By the way if it is a WatchDog crash you will not experience it running from Xcode. You would need to download from TestFlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.

It was Xcode 11.4 update that was causing the crash on 32-bit devices (iOS 10).
Crashes of iOS 13.4 were unrelated and different from the question I asked for.